# Rmarkdownon Kaggle: Can you spot what's going on?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kaggle

it's been a few days that im trying to run my Rmd on Kaggle, but it simply doesn't work.

The main reason (I guess) is that, somehow the console is reading the code as an R code, but im sure that I'm using Rmarkdown.

Therefore, the console reads a Text line as a code line, giving me the code error below:
[image]

Also, i tried to copy and edit other's people markdown, but i keep getting the same error line.

You can check my code here: https://www.kaggle.com/badluckmath/kernel4c85aae59c/edit/run/39891200

He's working perfectly on my Rstudio.

I'm looking for a huge help here, please!

Comment: Maybe df <- read.csv('master.csv')?

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with this for a week!

If i press the buttom to run code, it will simply give me this error message.

For that, i still don't know the solution. But since this is a premade Rmarkdown and i knew that it works, i simple used the Save (Commit) options and at the end, it worked.